# How long was a year 4 billion years ago, thus how long did it take the Earth to orbit the early Sun?

Tags: the-sun, orbit, earth

How long did it take the Earth to orbit the early Sun 4 billion years ago?

I'm not talking rotation, which I know has slowed over time. I'm talking about the orbital period of the early Earth. Was it zipping around the Sun like Mercury or did it take a much longer time than today?

Comment: The length of a year has been pretty much unchanged from 4 billion years ago to now.